# How to get a generic type which is defined on method in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Question 1:

Suggest I have a example like this:

```
public <T> void methodA(T req) { // doSth }

psvm(){
   ClassA aClass = new ClassA();
   aClass.<String>methodA("hello world");
}
```

then can I get type `String` in `methodA` without actually passing `String` to it?

Question 2:

If the previous example is transformed to this:

```
public <T> void methodA(Predicate<T> req) { // doSth }

psvm(){
   ClassA aClass = new ClassA();
   aClass.<String>methodA(item -> "hello world".equals(item));
}
```

I mean what was passed into `methodA` is no more a simple object but a lambda expression, also, can I get type `String` in `methodA`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking when you say you want to get type 'String' without passing in 'String'.  What are you hoping to accomplish in `methodA` that "get[ting] type 'String'" would achieve?

Comment: _then can i get type 'String' in methodA without actually passing 'String' to it?_ - no, impossible. You can call `req.getClass()`, but this isn't actually it. For example, `aClass.<List<String>>methodA(List.of())` compiles but it is IMPOSSIBLE to get `List<String>` from that (You can only get raw `List`). Similarly, `aClass.<Number>methodA(5.0)` makes it impossible (you'd get `Double`). Hence: __impossible__. In both cases.

Comment: when actually passing 'String'，methodA should be like this, methodA(T req, Class clazz), but i dont want this additional 'clazz' paremeter

Comment: If methodA going to be only call then you know that it expects a string so if you are having value as object you may check if it is type of string and then manually cast it and pass otherwise throw error for invalid type.

Comment: The additional class parameter still doesn't work; there is no instance of `Class<?>` which represents `List<String>`, for example. Look up 'super type tokens'. But first take your attitude of "I don't want to pass it" and check it at the door, otherwise you're... not gonna enjoy what you find with that search. Or, better yet, revisit why you think you need to know `String`. The best APIs just don't need to know. There is unfortunately no formulaic approach to designing APIs such that you don't need to know. You'd have to elaborate on your exact situation.

Comment: To follow up on rzwitserloot's comment, are you trying to do something like `if (req instanceof String)` or `Class<?> clazz = String.class` with the type parameter, and if so — why?  If that's not what you're trying to accomplish, what is it that you are actually trying to accomplish, and why?

Comment: I think I finally figured out what you're asking.  You want to know whether within `methodA` it is possible to determine the type or class of the generic type the method was called with, e.g. have a variable of type `String.class` within that method.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to determine the generic type of a generic method, due to type erasure.  At compile time, the generic type of the method is discarded, and there is no way to get this information at runtime.

```java
public class ClassA {
    public <T> void methodA(T req) {
        Class<T> genericType = ?; // Impossible to get e.g. Class<String>
        // [...]
    }

    public static void main(){
        new ClassA().methodA("hello world");
    }
}
```

There are certain scenarios where generic type information is retained (such as extending a generic class with a specific generic type, e.g. `class MyList implements List<String>`).  However, there is no way to do so for a generic method.

The best you could do, if you needed that information, would be to pass it in (which you stated you didn't want to do):

```java
public <T> void methodA(T req, Class<T> type) {
    // [...]
}
```

Another option, if all you needed was the type of the object passed in as opposed to the type of the generic method, would be to get the class of the object.

```java
public <T> void methodA(T req) {
    Class<?> type = req.getClass(); // Assuming req is non-null
    // [...]
}
```

Note that with this option in this specific example, the generic type is no longer being used for anything, so it can be dropped from the method signature.  This may not always be the case, such as if multiple parameters or a parameter and the return type needed matching generic types.

```java
public void methodA(Object req)
```

Comment: `Class<T> type = req.getClass();` will not compile. The result type of `req.getClass()` is `Class<? extends Object>`.

Comment: @Holger Good catch.  I fixed it to be `Class<?>`.  It still accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: But that makes `T` entirely obsolete. You could declare `public void methodA(Object req)` instead.

Comment: @Holger Depends on what the rest of the method is doing.  The asker didn't specify _why_ it was generic, so the `// [...]`/`doSth` code might be needing it.  But you're right, it might not be needed any more, depending on that.

Comment: Regardless of what happens inside `methodA`, you can replace every occurrence of `T` with `Object` and it makes no difference. Simply because all a method’s type parameter does, is refining the contract of the API provided by this method. Since the caller can stuff whatever it wants into this method, `T` has no impact at all. It’s different for `methodA(T req, Class<T> type)` because here, `T` is used to define a relationship between `req` and `type`.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, good points.  No point in having a generic method with only one generic parameter and zero generic return types.  That would be different if there were multiple parameters that needed the same generic type, or a return type that needed the same generic type.  I've updated the answer to address your point.